# How to create a particular 5 x 5 square colour map of the mean value of data points

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to create a specific type of colour map for some data. The data is in the form of a list with dimensions 300000 x 3, that is 300,000 sets of `{x, y, n}` where `x` and `y` are basically the $xy$ cartesian coordinates and `n` is a value either 0 or 1. Doing a list plot of the 300,000 points gives the following figure:

[image]

What I am trying to make is a colour map of this figure, that is made up of 5 x 5 evenly sized squares (so 25 all up), in which the colour-key denotes the mean of the n values of all the points within that square. Is this possible?

Please let me know if any additional information is needed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Join[RandomReal[1, {300000, 2}], RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {300000, 1}], 2];
Dimensions[data]
```

> {300000, 3}

```
nbins = 5;
binlims = Through[{Floor[Min@#, .01] &, Ceiling[Max@#, .01] &}@#] & /@ Transpose[data];
{xbins, ybins} = {##, -Subtract[##]/nbins} & @@@ Most[binlims];
binlists = BinLists[data, xbins, ybins, {0, 2, 2}];
binmeans =  Flatten /@ Map[Mean, binlists[[All, All, All, All, -1]], {-2}];

cft = Charting`FindTicks[{0, nbins}, {0, 1}];
MatrixPlot[binmeans, DataReversed -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  FrameTicks -> {{cft, cft}, {cft, cft}}]
```

[image]

With `nbins = 25` we get

[image]

Comment: I take it that if I would like to increase the number of squares, I just alter that 5 in the second line? Also, I tried changing it to 25 and it looks good, but there are a lot of data ticks. Is it possible to maybe only show every second, or even third data tick?

Comment: @Lagiacrus, right; changing 5 changes the number of bins.  Re ticks, please see the updated version.

Comment: So far the code appears to have been working well, but I just tried it for a similar situation in which the third element of the list can be either 0, 1, 2 or 3 (instead of the original 0 or 1) and in this case the binmeans never ends up with a value higher than 1. Is there a limit on the value that binmeans can take?

Comment: @Lagiacrus, you can change `{0, 2, 2}` in the definition of `binlists` to `{0,, 4, 4}`   if the third list can take values in `{0,1,2,3}`.