# 3d points projected to y-z plane and colorized according x-velocity using a grid for averaging

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color

This Question is related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176562/125) solved by 
@kglr and also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160592/nearest-number-of-neighbors-on-2d-regular-grid) solved by @Henrik Schumacher.

I have a set of 3d positions and velocities of particles, and want to colorize the projected positions to the xz plane according to the x-velocity.

kglr solved this by usinge the following code:

```
SeedRandom[1];
posdata = RandomReal[10, {1000, 3}];
veldata = RandomReal[{-0.5, +0.5}, {1000, 3}];

clfun[val_] := Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, val];

xvelzypos = posdata;
xvelzypos[[All, 1]] = veldata[[All, 1]];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax@veldata[[All, 1]];

legend = BarLegend[{clfun[Rescale[#, {xmin, xmax}]] &, {xmin, xmax}}, 
   LegendLabel -> "vx", LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 300}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 15}];

xvzyplot = 
  Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], 
       clfun[Rescale[#[[1]], {xmin, xmax}]], 
       Point[{#[[3]], #[[2]]}]} & /@ xvelzypos, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"z", ""}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20}, 
    ImageSize -> 400]];

Legended[Graphics[
  Inset[xvzyplot, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]], 
  AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@xvzyplot], legend]
```

The result is:

[image]

My question:

**I would like to use a certain grid on the yz plane with values dy and dz.
Each grid element should be color coded with the mean velocity of all particles that are projected to the corresponding grid element.**

I tried to use parts of the solution of @Henrik Schumacher, but did not succeed.

How can be my problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one a out of probably a million possibilities to achieve that:

```
SeedRandom[1];
posdata = RandomReal[10, {1000, 3}];
veldata = RandomReal[{-0.5, +0.5}, {1000, 3}];
ymin = 0.;
ymax = 10.;
zmin = 0.;
zmax = 10.;
dy = .5;
dz = .25;
m = Quotient[ymax - ymin, dy];
n = Quotient[zmax - zmin, dz];
boxcenters = Tuples[{
 Range[ymin + 0.5 dy, ymax - 0.5 dy, dy], 
 Range[zmin + 0.5 dz, zmax - 0.5 dz, dz]
 }];
```

If the aspect ration of the boxes is not equal to `1`, the trick is to rescale the positions so that we have quadratic boxes. This way, we can employ `Nearest` with `DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance` to find the correct box for each point.

```
normalizedboxcenters = Tuples[{Range[.5, m - 0.5], Range[.5, n - 0.5]}];
idx = Flatten@Nearest[
    normalizedboxcenters -> Automatic,
    Transpose[{(#2 - ymin)/dy, (#3 - zmin)/dz} & @@ Transpose[posdata]]
    ,
    {1, 0.5},
    DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance
    ];
```

Have a index of the box for each point, we build a sparse matrix that will do the summing up by matrix-vector multiplication. `Total[A, {2}]` tells us, how many points are in each box which also helps us to perform the averaging.

```
A = SparseArray[
   Transpose[{idx, Range[Length[idx]]}] -> 1.,
   {Length[boxcenters], Length[posdata]},
   0.
   ];
meanvelocities = (A.veldata)/Clip[Total[A, {2}], {1., \[Infinity]}];
meanxvelocities = meanvelocities[[All, 1]];
```

Assigning some colors and plotting the result.

```
cols = ColorData["DarkRainbow"] /@ Rescale[meanxvelocities];
Graphics[
 Transpose[{
   cols,
   Rectangle @@@ Transpose[{
      Transpose[Transpose[boxcenters] - 0.5 {dy, dz}],
      Transpose[Transpose[boxcenters] + 0.5 {dy, dz}]
      }]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Of course, you are free to prettify the output and to add labels and stuff. But I guess, you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution ,,, it helps me a lot

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I tried your solution with my real data set and have a problem with it. Can you please have short look on it? Thank you. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TXoUllMcws-ax1SMQFAd9QMeE4t5jrGv

Comment: Okay, I found a typo of mine. Please try again with `boxcenters = Tuples[{Range[ymin + 0.5 dy, ymax - 0.5 dy, dy],Range[zmin + 0.5 dz, zmax - 0.5 dz, dz]}];`.

Comment: Not also that you it is possible that you get your image reflected with respect to the main diagonal. If you have pixels that are squares, it might be more efficient with `ArrayPlot[ArrayReshape[Rescale[meanxvelocities], {m, n}], 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]]`.

Comment: Yes this is the solution … perfekt

Comment: It depends. Arrays and images are index differently. Just give it a try. You might figure out what exactly to do if you enter a less symmetric input image and apply `Transpose` and `Reverse` to the array until the outputs fits to the input. But I guess, `ArrayPlot[ArrayReshape[Rescale[meanxvelocities], {m, n}], 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"],
 DataReversed -> True
 ]` should be fine.

Comment: Good to hear that!

Comment: First of all let me once again to thank you for your additional help. Everything works perfect also with other data sets. I am not sure if I should ask you here something in addition (or should I put it into a new question? Please give me your advice). 1. How can I show beside your `ArrayPlot` a legend so that it is visible which color represents which mean velocity.  2. Is it possible to use my own color function `clfun[val_] := Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, val];` instead of `ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]` for the `ArrayPlot` and the legend.

Comment: Hey Lenoil, yes, usually it is good practice to open a new question. But this one is quickly and easily answered: Adding the option `PlotLegends -> Automatic` to the `ArrayPlot` should do the job. (Have also a look into the "Options" section in the documentation of `ArrayPlot`.) And yes, every other color function should do.

Comment: Could you please have a look on that question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189592/removing-non-associated-2d-points-for-preparing-remaining-data-as-input-for-a-ge

Answer (score 4):

#### [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html)  and `"TreatRepeatedEntries"`

Related Q/As :

- [Mathematica fast 2D binning algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203344/990168)
- [Optimising 2D binning code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17742/125)
- [How to create a particular 5 x 5 square colour map of the mean value of data points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166714/125)

```
vvalues = xvelzypos[[All, 1]];
epsilon = 1*^-10;
indexes = 1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) 20 Rescale[xvelzypos[[All, {2, 3}]]]];
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries"->(Mean[{##}]&)}];
binmeansV = SparseArray[indexes -> vvalues];
System`SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}];

MatrixPlot[binmeansV, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
 BaseStyle -> Opacity[.7], ColorFunction -> clfun, 
 ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, 
 FrameTicks -> {{#, #} & @ Transpose[{#, # - .5} & @Range[.5, 10.5, 1]],
    {#, #} & @ Transpose[{#, # - .5} &@Range[.5, 10.5, 1]]}]
```

[image]

#### [`BinLists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BinLists.html)

Using 5 bins each of size 2 for the horizontal and vertical coordinates and a single bin for velocity:

```
xbinspec = ybinspec = {0, 11, 2}; 
vbinspec ={-1, 1, 2};
binmeans = Flatten[Map[Mean[Last /@ #] &, 
  BinLists[RotateLeft /@ xvelzypos, xbinspec , ybinspec , vbinspec], {-3}], {3}][[1]];
matrixplot = MatrixPlot[Riffle[#, #] &[Riffle[#, #] & /@ binmeans], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.7], 
  ColorFunction -> clfun, ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, DataReversed -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{#, #} &@Transpose[{#, # - .5} &@Range[.5, 10.5, 1]], 
    {#, #} &@Transpose[{#, # - .5} &@Range[.5, 10.5, 1]]}]
```

[image]

Add the option `Epilog -> xvzyplot[[1]]` to get

[image]

Comment: Your explanation and solution is excellent … I will go through it. My real data consist of about 10^6 to 10^7 data points. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I tried your solution with my real data set and have a problem with it. Can you please have look on the following notebook? Thank you. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JQMop_lcxI2pL5tUvH9A17KOF3tTV0s5
My data range is not exactly squared, this is one problem. I know that I did not properly set the `PlotRange`.  I tried to adapt it to `MinMax` of `posdata[[All,2]]` and `posdata[[All,3]]` but it did not help. How can I increase the number of row and columns?

Comment: @Lenoil, for the `SparseArray` method, you can use `indexes = 
 1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) {numberofxbins, numberofybins} # & /@ Rescale[xvelzypos[[All, {2, 3}]]]]` ti have different number of bins for the first and second dimension.

Comment: @L, Btw, you also need to change the `PlotRange` option from `MatrixPlot`.